# Finding optimal $\theta$ via maximize cost function

Tags: optimization

I want to find a variable $\theta\in R^n$ subject to maximizing the value of $f(\theta)$ where $||\theta||=1$ and $f$ is a black-box function. Is there any solution or library help me in this case?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I would try some form of genetic learning, but be careful that it might converge to a local maximum.

Comment: Thanks. t's good but I want a simpler solution.

Comment: I'm not sure there is anything simple, it's a complex problem.